# how to add default product sorting of woocommerce on the custom page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I have created a custom page template in which I load the listing of products using WooCommerce functions but not templates. But now I want to implement the default WooCommerce sorting functionality on my custom page template. How can I implement this?

I do not want to use WooCommerce templates. I simply want to  make a sorting function like the default on with the use of WooCommerce functions.

Here is my custom page template code:

```
<?php
/**
 Template Name: Shop page custom layout template
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php
    $full_product_list = array();
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' =>array( 'product', 'product_variation' ), 'posts_per_page' => -1,) );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $theid = get_the_ID();
    $product = new WC_Product($theid); ?>
    <?php $product_url=$product->add_to_cart_url(); ?>
    <ul><li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php
   echo '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
    echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) : 
       echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', '<span class="onsale">' . __( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>', $post, $product ); 
    endif; 
    if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
    <?php endif; 
    if ( $rating_html = $product->get_rating_html() ) : ?>
    <?php echo $rating_html; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

  <?php $cart_url="/construction/shop/?add-to-cart=".$theid; ?>
   <a class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_sku="" data-product_id="<?php echo $theid ?>" data-quantity="1" href="<?php echo $cart_url; ?>" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>
    </a></li></ul>
<?php
endwhile; wp_reset_query();

?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "default Woocommerce sorting functionality" because the order products are displayed in depends on the functionality attached to the page showing products. But assuming you want to sort by the product title, change your query to this:

`$loop = new wp_query(array('post_type' =>array('product', 'product_variation'), 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'));`

That will sort by title in ascending order, which I'm guessing is what you wanted.